# Javascript/jquery does not work in twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter bootstrap v3 and when I open the modal windows I would like to do some jquery/javascript. But it does not let me use any javascipt or jquery . The code works fine within a page but when I move it into modal it does not work. For example this is what I have tried , very simple function but it does not work in modal:

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
```

and in the modal I have this:

```
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
```

How can I make that small script work when the bootstrap modal is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have moved the script within the modal it self and it works .

Answer (score -1):

put your code inside document.ready callback. Use jquery to do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $( "p" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: That will attempt to bind the event handler when the initial document is ready, not when the modal code adds the new elements to the DOM (which is a long time after the ready event fires)

Comment: He didn't specify that modal content is filled dynamically. My bootstrap modals are loaded with all the page.

Comment: sorry i didnt mantion my modal is dynamically loaded from another page , that was my issue. thank you anyway